# Saving structure from GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I made software in MATLAB to detect some features. Once I have the centroid of the feature, I would like to press a button and save the feature to a .m file.

Since I will have different features, each structure, when the button is pressed, should add itself to the same file... at the end I would like to have a vector of structures. In C++ it would be something like generating an empty vector, v... And when the button is pressed I would call something like v.push_back().. How can I do this?

I implemented everything already. I just need to know how to create a vector of structures (I do not know the size of the vector) and then I need to know how to add a structure to the vector. At the end I need an .m file with a vector of structures.

Comment: Learn the basics using the matlab [help](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html)

Comment: ??? is this a help??...

Comment: From your question it looks like you dont know where to begin - so I suggested that you look at the Mathworks documentation where you can learn the Matlab basics.  If update your question and put in what you have tried (actual code) then you are more likely to get help (from me at least).

Answer (score 0):

First define an empty array like this:

```
x = [];
```

You can add any number of structures or elements in this array:

```
x1 = struct ('item1', 2, 'item2', 3);
x  = [x x1];
x2 = struct ('item1', 4, 'item2', 5);
x  = [x x2];
```

Comment: what about a 2 dimension structure? how do i create one? thanks

Comment: provide an example of structure

Comment: My structure is "structure: field1 field2".. i need to press a button in the gui and add structure to an array of structures....or creating the structure with 2 dimensions...